# UIGraphicsBeginImageContext with parameters

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am taking a screenshot in my application.  I am able to take the screenshot.

Now I want to take the screenshot by specifying the x and y coordinate.  Is that possible?

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( self.view.bounds.size );
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(  )];
UIImage* aImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(  );
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(c, 0, -40);    // <-- shift everything up by 40px when drawing.
[self.view.layer renderInContext:c];
UIImage* viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: @barbgal: Use CGContextScaleCTM to resize. Also, you may need a smaller context (change the argument to UIGraphicsBeginImageContext).

Comment: @Barbgal: No. `CGSize size=self.view.bounds.size; UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(size.width,size.height-40)); CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();`

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a newer retina display device, your code should factor in the resolution by using UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions instead of UIGraphicsBeginImageContext:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size,YES,2.0);
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(c, 0, -40);    // <-- shift everything up by 40px when drawing.
[self.view.layer renderInContext:c];
UIImage* viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This will render the retina display image context.

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like this, way easier than all those complex calculations

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithView:(UIView *)view {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions([view bounds].size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);

    [[view layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Swift version

```
//Capture Screen
func capture()->UIImage {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
    self.view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image

}
```

Answer (score 0):

swift version

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size)
    let image: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    CGContextTranslateCTM(image, 0, -40)
    // <-- shift everything up by 40px when drawing.
    self.view.layer.renderInContext(image)
    let viewImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil)
```