# iOS Screenshot part of the screen

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an App that takes a screenshot of a UIImageView with the following code:

```
-(IBAction) screenShot: (id) sender{

 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sshot.frame.size);
 [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
 UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage,nil, nil, nil);


}
```

This works well but I need to be able to position where I take the screenshot basically I need to grad only a third of the screen (center portion). I tried using

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize 150,150);
```

But have found that every thing is taken from 0,0 coordinates, has anyone any idea how to position this correctly.

Comment: Same problem occurs for me also I could not found any solution to it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well the screenshot is taken from a canvas you draw.
So instead of drawing your layer in the whole context, with a reference to top left corner, you will draw it where you want to take the screenshot....

```
//first we will make an UIImage from your view
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *sourceImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//now we will position the image, X/Y away from top left corner to get the portion we want
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sshot.frame.size);
[sourceImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-50, -100)];
UIImage *croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(croppedImage,nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: What is `sshot.frame.size`?  Did you mean `self.view.frame.size`?

Comment: It's the size of the screenshot. You could change that line to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(200,200));' to make a 200X200 screenshot image

Answer (score 14):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194388/uigraphicsbeginimagecontext-help)

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sshot.frame.size);
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(c, 150, 150);    // <-- shift everything up to required position when drawing.
[self.view.layer renderInContext:c];
UIImage* viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: Yes, this is actually a better solution

Answer (score 7):

Use this method to crop if u have image with specfic rect to crop:

```
-(UIImage *)cropImage:(UIImage *)image rect:(CGRect)cropRect
{
   CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], cropRect);
   UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
   CGImageRelease(imageRef);
   return img;
}
```

Use like this:

```
UIImage *img = [self cropImage:viewImage rect:CGRectMake(150,150,100,100)]; //example
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like you can refer [this](https://github.com/AalokParikh/SSPhotoCropperViewController) code.

In this example you can get the image covered by the rect from any position and any zoom scale.

Happy Coding :)

Some extracted code for reference is as below

Main function or code used to crop the photo

```
- (UIImage *) croppedPhoto
{
    CGFloat ox = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    CGFloat oy = self.scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat zoomScale = self.scrollView.zoomScale;
    CGFloat cx = (ox + self.cropRectangleButton.frame.origin.x + 15.0f) * 2.0f / zoomScale;
    CGFloat cy = (oy + self.cropRectangleButton.frame.origin.y + 15.0f) * 2.0f / zoomScale;
    CGFloat cw = 300.0f / zoomScale;
    CGFloat ch = 300.0f / zoomScale;
    CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(cx, cy, cw, ch);

    NSLog(@"---------- cropRect: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(cropRect));
    NSLog(@"--- self.photo.size: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(self.photo.size));

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self.photo CGImage], cropRect);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    NSLog(@"------- result.size: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(result.size));

    return result;
}
```

The details how to use the example is given [here](http://www.ardalahmet.com/2011/10/17/ssphotocropperviewcontroller-a-custom-viewcontroller-that-provides-ui-for-cropping-photos-in-ios-apps/).

Enjoy Coding :)