# Screenshot at required CGRect on UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I made a 3x3 cell layout with UIViews. So there are 9 UIViews!!!

I am trying to screenshot these 9 UIviews individually. But Whatever I tried, I can only screenshot the 1st UIview.

HEre is the screenshot of the main view that holds the 9 subviews:

[image]

And I want to screenshot the second tile by sending _tile2, but the final result I get is _tile1 only.

:[image]

Here is the code:

```
     [self saveImage:[self screenshotTile:_tile2]]; //_tile1,_tile2...._tile9 gave the same result
```

What I believe is If I send the _tile1, it should screenshot the _tile1 area on the self.view, and  If I send the _tile2, it should screenshot the _tile2 area on the self.view .But whatever I send, it only captures the _tile1 area on the view.

```
-(void)saveImage:(UIImage *)img{

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil);
}

-(UIImage *)screenshotTile :(UIView *)imgV{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imgV.frame.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    _tileImg1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return _tileImg1;
 }
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687909/ios-screenshot-part-of-the-screen) solution which suggests to shift the image after taking the screenshot, but it didnt work too:

```
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sshot.frame.size);
     [sourceImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-50, -100)]; // I tried -imgV.frame.origin.v, -imgV.frame.origin.y but it didnt work for me!!!
```

Comment: Why are you setting an ivar (`_tileImg1`) in `screenshotTile:`?

Comment: I set it because, in future If I want to add further enhancements to the captured image I need it right ?

Comment: i updated the question .Please check it!!! Do you have any idea why this happens ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few trials, I  managed to get it worked by using this code:

```
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(c, -imgV.frame.origin.x, -imgV.frame.origin.y);

[self.view.layer renderInContext:c];
```

I need to shift the context x axis and y axis according to the tile frame. The context always starts from the 0,0 point, So I need to move the image according to the tile frame.

In the process of doing this, I encountered one wierd error which stopped me in saving the images to the camera roll:

`Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died`

I am not sure why and how it occured. After few trials, the error disappeared. I dont even know how ti reproduce it!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You pass a tile to the `screenshotTile:` method. In that method, you never actually **use** the tile. Maybe you want to send `renderInContext:` to `imgV.layer`, not to `self.view.layer`.

Comment: This is not the case I need rob!!! If I send imgV.layer I will get the screenshot of the tile!!!! But I need the screenshot of the self.view.layer under the tile!!!! As you can see, there are 9 colored tiles, If I screenshot the tile, I get just the color tile as image. But I need the image under the tile which is self.view.layer!!!!

Comment: I am sending the tile to screenshot method because, I need the screenshot of tile frame and tile size on the self.view.layer